# Can someone fix a typo in this tag?

Tags: support, tags

I discovered this tag: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/austroneisan

But it should be `nesian` not `neisan`, right?

I don't have enough rep to fix it.

Comment: I'm probably not qualified to comment on spelling errors, but if it is wrong I think the easiest thing to do would be to just create the properly-spelled tag and retag the existing 3 questions. Orphaned tags automatically go away after a while.

Comment: I did not expect that to work with my rep so low, but i was able to create the new tag and suggest edits to those questions removing the wrong one and adding the right one. Let's see what happens next.

Comment: @KateGregory - 150 rep is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like [all](https://history.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/62980) [of](https://history.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/62979) [your](https://history.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/62978) edits have been approved, and the three mistagged questions now use the correct spelling, [austronesian](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/austronesian).